# Did git rebase on origin by mistake

Tags: git

How do I revert my rebase? I was on local branch(abc) and wanted it to rebase it with origin. Following are the commands that I issued:

```
git checkout live
(On branch live)
git pull
```

After this, I THINK I forgot to switch back to my local branch 'abc' and I started rebasing it and when I ran 'git status' command, I realized that I rebased live branch locally.

```
git status
On branch live
Your branch is ahead of 'remotes/origin/live' by 13 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

I don't want to push anything but and want to delete those 13 commits that it is showing. What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: rebase doesn't normally magically make 13 commits appear locally.  It does set ORIG_HEAD so you can use that or the reflog to go backwards.

Comment: Did you get your answer yet? Don't forget to acknowledge whether or not if you got this issue fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git reset --hard <SHA>` to go back to your original state. I will recommend to create an experiment branch first.

Also read and check the following documentation - http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Answer (score 2):

In general, read `git reflog` to figure out where you want to reset to.

In this case you seem to know you want to reset to `origin/live` (but do check `git log origin/live..live` to be sure).

Once you know what you're resetting to, run `git reset --hard commit-to-reset-to`, in this case `git reset --hard origin/live`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `git reflog` command to show you the reflog for your current branch.  This is data maintained locally that has a history of each commit that your local branches pointed to.  You can use this data to find the commit that your local branch pointed to before the rebase.

If rebasing is the last operation you performed then `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` should undo this operation (and it will also discard any changes you have made to the working tree).

Comment: How do I get to know which are those 13 commits git hub is talking about?

Comment: You would have to inspect them manually and figure that out. You could also use `git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --graph --decorate --all` to see the entire history in graph form.  You may be able to determine where to reset to from that graph.